# Create an instance, execute a long script and then kill it

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm starting to use Google Cloud Engine, what I need to do is to use the python-api to:

1. Create a new instance (i'm already doing this)
2. Execute a python script, a very long one taking about 12 hours
3. Once the execution is finished, delete the instance

Now im using a startup-script, but I'm having some problems as it's not loading conda correctly, and I need to run 'conda activate'. I'm actually thinking a startup script might not be the best way...

Also, is there any way to monitor the progress of the script on the instance? I found this getSerialPort method, but seems I need to do a sort of busy-waiting calling it all the time and printing the output till it finishes.

Thanks,
Marcelo

Comment: Do you mean compute engine or app engine? In other words, a VM or a container? I guess you mean a compute engine.

Comment: Sorry, compute engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable interactive serial console access for a specific instance (there is also a project wide setting):

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-name \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
```

Then listen to the logging on the serial port:

```
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port instance-name
```

Comment: Yep, but this is a very uneasy way to do it. Is there any way to monitor that endpoint for updates on the serial console and automatically print them on my terminal main script?

Comment: If you only need to view serial port output, you can call the getSerialPortOutput method, and it seems that you are already using it. Another way is using [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output) to read the information that your instance has written to its serial port. For more information, please read [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output).